# Expectation of Rational numbers raised to power.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $q_{1},q_{2},....,q_{n},.....$ be an ennumeration of rational numbers in the set $[0,1]\cup (5,6)$ .

Let $X$ be a random variable with pmf:-

$P(X=q_{j})=\frac{1}{2^{j}}$.

Then what is $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\mathbb{E}(X^{k})\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}$$.

I think the answer should be $6$. I am able to show that the upper-bound for the limit is $6$. But I am unable to show that the lower bound is $6$.

$$\left(\mathbb{E}(X^{k})\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{k}_{j}}{2^{j}}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{6^{k}}{2^{j}}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\leq (6^{k})^{\frac{1}{k}} =6$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you show your work?

Comment: There is literally nothing to show that $6$ is an upper bound. But for your satisfaction I'll edit it in.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews . Can you tell me how to proceed?. Should I consider rearrangement of terms of the series?

Comment: No idea what the correct answer is. My last comment was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For any $i$ $$E(X^k)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{q_j^k}{2^j}>\frac {q_{i}^k}{2^i }.$$ So $$E(X^k)^{1/k}> \frac{q_i}{2^{i/k}}.$$

Then let $k\to\infty.$

Comment: This gives answer as 6 right?. I mean the supremum of $q_{i}$ is 6

Comment: I deliberately left that out.

Comment: Yeah . I mean once we find the lower bound is 6 it follows from sandwich. My question was entirely about proving that 6 is a lower bound. Now since it holds for any i. taking the supremum on both sides should not affect it as it is the "least upper bound". Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Right, you get $$\liminf_{k\to\infty} E(X^k)^{1/k}\geq q_i$$ for all $i,$ so $$\liminf_{k\to\infty} E(X^k)^{1/k}\geq \sup_i q_i$$

Comment: More generally, if $X$ is a non-negative random variable, and $x_0$ is a real number such that $$P(X\geq x_0)>0\tag1$$ then $$\liminf E(X^k)^{1/k}\geq x_0.$$ Then the limit is the supremeum of the $x_0$ satisfying $(1).$